# how to trigger an Oozie workflow when previous workflow completes

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I am using Oozie workflows to import many tables from different oracle servers. Currently, I have developed a workflow for each of these tables that I want to sqoop into Hadoop. This does a basic sqoop, then does some transformation and creation of hive tables.

Where I have got stuck is, I want to schedule one workflow to run which, is fine. (I have done that), then I want the rest of the workflows to execute on completion of the previous one.

I have been looking at bundles but have not managed to find a solution. I hope some of you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a parent or wrapping workflow that calls each workflow in series (as part of the ok state transition). This is documented as a sub-workflow action:

- http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Sub-workflow_Action